# How to submit the form using JQuery and not with full postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

How to submit the form using JQuery and not with full postback ?

Right now I am able to submit the form with full postback. But it takes time to respond back.

Any help to share the Video tutorial will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this url for details http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/yourposturl",
        type: "post",
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
        //write code here manage "data"
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("failure");
      $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
  }   
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is use the jQuery ajax method or one of the shorthand methods.  If you have a form like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

you can submit it like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.post("/mycontroller/myaction", $("#myform").serialize(), function(data){
        //do something with the response from the controller via the data object
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/